# How to render twig variables in external CSS file?

Tags: css, variables, twig

I'm building twig pages and I want to load external CSS files in the HTML `<head>`. In my CSS I'm using dynamic paths for the images, e.g.

`background-image:url("{{file.find('campaign/assets/icon.png')}}");`

I know it's possible to load the CSS using  `{% load "css/styles.css" %}` but I want to keep the stylesheet in a separate file that I can cache client-side instead of keeping the code inline in the `<head>`.

I searched on SO and found several questions, mostly related to how to write CSS with twig, but none on how to process my CSS file with twig code in it while keeping the file external.

I tried using `<link rel...>` but it just sees the twig code as plain text. Is it even possible to do what I want? Perhaps pre-process the CSS+twig and transform it to a plain CSS file before serving?

Comment: In short, create a `style.php`, create rewrite rule from `style.css` to `style.php`, create a view named, `style.twig.html`. Let `style.php` render that view with `twig`.

Comment: you can create a *.css.twig file, calling it from a controller, and linking it with a defined route...

Comment: @pbenard That is an interesting method. Never thought on just registering a route for it. Aren't you afraid that boot-up time of the framework you are using is gonna cause a (too big) delay?

Comment: @DarkBee I use this way for big data multisite, it does its job, maybe a cache setup could be usefull.... Here is a live exemple : https://www.montblancnaturalresort.com/css/customstylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this is by rewriting your `style.css` to a `php` file which is able to render your `twig`-based css file

*html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script>
        $(function() {

        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^css/style.css css/style.php [QSA,L]
```

*style.php*

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//any code to boot up your $twig environment

echo $twig->render('css/style.twig.css', [
    'rules' => [
        'h1' => ['font-size' => '26 px', 'font-weight' => 'bold', 'color' => 'red', ],
    ],
]);
```

*style.twig.css*

```
{% for selector, selector_rules in rules %}
    {{ selector }} {
        {% for key, value in selector_rules %}
            {{ key }}: {{ value }};
        {% endfor %}
    }
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi don't know if this solution is usefull, but this solve my problem. My situation is i have a hero section that load an image in a css :before definition, but i would like the image can be changed dynamically and i use TWIG.

**CSS Before:**

```
.hero_single.version_2:before {
  background: url(../img/home_section_2.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**CSS After:**

```
.hero_single.version_2:before {
  background: var(--hero-image-url) center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**TWIG After:**

```
{% block customVendorsCss %}
{% set test = 'home_section_2.jpg' %}
<style>
:root {
  --hero-image-url: url(../img/{{ test }});
}
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

In my example i have a block ans define a css variable that have a twig var inside (in this example the var is static, but will be a var that came from a database).

This solve my problem with the css :before.